# Handle Variants in Live streaming using HLS

Tags: live-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I was watching some videos in `twitch.tv` to be sure how variants work for live streaming.

I see that, in the beginning a master manifest is downloaded and then a playlist is selected. After this, I used `tomcast` to throttling network and I waited until videos resolution changes to other variant, but it did not happened never (video was lagged but continued downloading the variant video selected in the beginning).

My question is, if `live-HLS` adapts the streaming with the variants once it started to play.

Answer (score 0):

The selection of what variant to play is done by the player. Every player is different, and Twitch uses their own. To understand why that specific player is behaving that specific way would require Twitch to comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I test if variant is selected then. Could you tell me if you know a player that changes variant in time with the criteria on master manifest?. Currently I am using only html video tag to test. I am simulating a live stream with VOD manifests and now I would like to add a master manifest to handle variants.